# Does rsync delete local files if they were deleted on source folder?

Tags: linux, backup, rsync

Here's what I'm trying to do:

In essence, get files from one net storage device synced to another net storage device.

The solution was to rsync from the source net storage to a local machine. Then rsync from local machine to destination net storage.

But it just hit me. I needed files that were deleted from the source net storage to be deleted on the local machine. Does rsync mirror them iow, delete files that aren't on the destination? Or does it only reduce the amount of data transfer required?

Hope I'm making it clear?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

there's a `--delete` option.  without this, it won't delete old files.